# Accessing mongodb database that doesnt have authentication giving error

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I try to access mongodb database that doesn't have autentication from my code but it giving error
`MongoParseError: Invalid empty username provided`

in my code i leave username and password as empty string

here's the code :

```
const targetConnectionOptions = {
  host: config.get('MONGODB_HOST'),
  user: '',
  password: '',
};
```

is there any solutions for this ? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You are explicitely trying to log in with an empty user name and an empty password, it's normal Mongo rejects them. Remove username and password entirely, or at least try to set them as `null` instead of empty strings.